# jQuery Slider not working on my site but works in JSFIDDLE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I have a slider that is not working on my own website but when i add it to JSFIDDLE it works!

My site: http://www.gymboss.net/gymboss-features.html#timerDetails

Working on JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/t4H5L/3/

I cant explain why.

```
 $(window).load(function(){
      $("#sticker-nav").sticky({ topSpacing: 0, className:"hey" });

      $('ul.nav').localScroll(function(){

      });
    });

    $('#main-slider').liquidSlider();

    var d = $(".connect-gallery"),
        e = function () {
            var a = [];
            return $.each(d.find("figure"), function (b, c) {
                a.push(c.className.replace("-stage", ""))
            }), a
        }(),
        f = 0,
        g = function () {
            var a = [];
            return $.each(e, function (b, c) {
                a.push(c + "-scene")
            }), a
        }().join(" "),
        h = function (a) {
            $(".connect-nav li").removeClass("selected").eq(a).addClass("selected"), d.removeClass(g).addClass(e[a] + "-scene"), f = a
        };
    $(".connect-nav li").click(function () {
        h($(this).data("index"))
    }), $(".gallery-nav").click(function () {
        var a = $(this).data("direction"),
            b, c = f.length - 1;
        a === "next" && (b = f < e.length - 1 ? f += 1 : 0), a === "previous" && (b = f > 0 ? f -= 1 : e.length - 1), h(b)
    }), h(0)
```

Comment: The slider with the GYm Boss device ? it works for me. I used Google Chrome.

Comment: hmm, not working for my in Chrome, FF, IE

Answer (score 0):

Have a look through the console. There are three errors you will need to resolve (they may or may not be causing your problem). The first one *certainly* looks like the culprit, and is probably related to [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) being enabled somehow.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.liquid-slider-custom.min.js:6
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jcarousel' custom.js:21
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dispatchEvent' prototype.js:5734
```

Comment: Well, it sure was there before ;) You'd be better to use a [CDN](http://cdnjs.com/) to load jQuery and jCarousel. Still seeing the `jcarousel` error in custom.js -- see if you can resolve that and you'll probably be good to go.

Comment: whats more interesting is the cached page has the slider working but with the same jcarousel error: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:D7z5SeCxB-MJ:gator3058.hostgator.com/~flygary/gymboss-features.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 0):

You jquery-1.10.1.min.js file doesnt load. url: http://www.gymboss.net/js/jquery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js return 404 error.
Check file name and path.

Comment: refresh your browser, you caught it while i was adding and removing files. should be back to 1.7.2